# How to allocate CGAL's Halfedge struture in shared memory?

Tags: c++, geometry, ipc, shared-memory, cgal

I want to continue my previous question which was misunderstood as related to 2D geometry and as a result I get no satisfying answer ([Share CGAL's geometry between processes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657030/share-cgals-geometry-between-processes-in-c)) and ask it once again, but this time properly, highlighting, I'm talking about 3D Cgals Polyhedron Geometry.

In CGAL manual  I read that it’s possible to instantiate HalfedgeDS.  I want to place it in shared memory so that other process could use it (please note, it has to be shared between processes, not threads). How to make my custom allocator that suit my needs, so I could put it as Alloc parameter? And what about other parameters  – “Traits” and “Items” – normally you don’t have to worry about it when you use only top level classes. Below I post the most interesting fragment, that I've found uin the CGALs manual, which I think could be helpful:

> A HalfedgeDS is a class template and will be used
>   as argument for other class templates, for example CGAL::Polyhedron_3.
>   The template parameters to instantiate the
>   HalfedgeDS will be provided by this other class
>   template. Therefore, the three template parameters and their meaning
>   are mandatory. We distinguish between the template
>   HalfedgeDS and an instantiation of it.

Note that I am interested only in solutions related to 3D geometry.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are interested in using [CGAL::HalfedgeDS_list](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/HalfedgeDS_ref/Class_HalfedgeDS_list.html), which is the one used by default by the Polyhedron class. As all model of the HalfedgeDS concept, it has an allocator as template parameter.

Then using a shared memory allocator (like [boost interprocess allocator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)) will do the job.

Comment: Your answer is the excellent abstract of the problem I've outlined in this and my previous question. Unfortunately you didn’t write anything new :(

Comment: @danilo2 Have you tried with boost "interprocess allocator"? Isn't this allocator answer to your question?

Comment: This allocator could be used, but then I need to provide the “Traits” and “Items” parameters. The problem is, i do NOT know what should I pass as THESE parameters to initialize HalfedgeDS? (Or CGAL::Polyhedron_3 with Halfedge container in shared memory)

Comment: `typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;`
`typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3< K, CGAL::Polyhedron_items_3,CGAL::HalfedgeDS_default,My_allocator> My_polyhedron;`

Comment: Thank you sloriot for this tip, but could you provide a little more information how to implement My_allocator? According to CGALs documentation ""The fourth parameter Alloc requires a standard allocator for STL container classes." - how to make std::allocator on shared memory? When I'm trying to use the boost allocator I get compilation error (saying I need std one).

Comment: The sample code, you're asking for can be found here: http://pastebin.com/wFV3KxCM. I would be very thnakfull for help with it :)

Comment: You indeed need to pass the allocator to the HDS class. I've made the modifications in Polyhedron and HDS to give it a try but then I'm stuck with another internal container. I'll try to investigate and come back to you then.

Comment: Hi! Do you have any further ideas?